# Issue in Login with facebook in android application

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am using **Login with FaceBook** functionality for my Android app. in which I am facing an issue, with existing FaceBook app in device.

I am using [SessionLoginSample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample) for sign in with facebook. It is display one custom view for login with facebook and it is working fine but
If there is  facebook application installed in device then it will not display its custom view instead it navigate to facebook application and display its login page (or View. **see below image**) and if I login in facebook app I am not getting proper response from facebook authentication process.

**Facebook application login view**

[image]

And if there is no facebook application installed in device then it will  display its custom view and all whole flow for particular functionality is working fine.

**SessionLoginSample's custom View**

[image]

Is there any way to display SessionLoginSample's custom View always even if there is facebook application installed in device Or any alternative related this issue?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805843/issessionvalid-returns-no-when-facebook-native-application-is-installed?rq=1

Comment: and also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853965/facebook-sample-session-login-applicatiom-not-working-when-native-facebook-app-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by this code section in my app.
This will give response in both scenario, i.e Native app is installed or it is not installed.

Here is a link for thi

```
import com.facebook.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.DialogError;
import com.facebook.Facebook;
import com.facebook.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;

facebook = new Facebook( APP_ID );
mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner( facebook );
loginWithFB();


public void loginWithFB()
    {
    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {         
     facebook.authorize(Login.this, new String[] {"publish_stream","read_stream", "offline_access"}, //Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, 
            new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();                                
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {Log.e("FB:","Facebook Error" );}

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {Log.e("FB:","Error" );}

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {}
           });
    }
}


@Override
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data )
    {
        super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );
        facebook.authorizeCallback( requestCode, resultCode, data );
    }
```